Linear differential expression $L(x,t,D,D_t)$
The following is taken from "Parabolic Boundary Value Problems" by Eidelman.
Let \begin{equation}L(x,t,D,D_t)\hspace{4cm}(1)\end{equation} be a linear differential expression of an arbitrary order with complex-value coefficients depending on $x$ and $t$ and defined on $\Omega$. For any point $(x,t)\in \Omega$ the function \begin{equation}L(x,t,i\zeta,p)\hspace{4cm}(2)\end{equation} where $\zeta$ is an n-dimensional vector with coordinates $\zeta_1,\dots,\zeta_n$ and $p$ is a complex scalar parameter, is a polynomial in $\zeta_k$ and $p$.
How did we transition from formulation (1) to (2)? Can you provide some reference?
